# Double Inner Join Too Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

Hey I've been looking around and couldn't find the solution to my problem. 
I have a nutritional database that has 3 tables. All 3 tables have the name, nutritional content, and units of measurement for a single item. I want to return the items with the highest amount of a single nutrient, ie. protein.

My current query takes about 3 seconds to get the entry, which will be a problem since I'm going to have this query multiple times in a page for multiple nutrients. Any help is appreciated.

```
food_des - about 8,000 entries
+-------+---------+--------+
|NDB_No |Long_Desc|Fd_Group|
+-------+---------+--------+
|01001  |Banana   |0100    |
|01002  |Apple    |0102    |
+-------+---------+--------+

nut_data - about 600,000 entries
+-------+-------+--------+
|NDB_No |Nutr_No|Nutr_Val|
+-------+-------+--------+
|01001  |318    |55.5    |
|01001  |320    |1.1     |
|01002  |318    |30.2    |
|01002  |325    |12.3    |
+-------+-------+--------+

nut_def - about 150 entries
+-------+--------+-----+
|Nutr_No|NutrDesc|Units|
+-------+--------+-----+
|318    |Carbs   |g    |
|319    |Energy  |kcal |
|320    |Protein |g    |
|325    |Iron    |mg   |
+-------+--------+-----+

SELECT food_des.Long_Desc, nut_data.Nutr_Val, nutr_def.Units
FROM food_des
INNER JOIN nut_data
ON food_des.NDB_No=nut_data.NDB_No
INNER JOIN nutr_def
ON nut_data.Nutr_No=nutr_def.Nutr_No
WHERE nutr_def.NutrDesc="Vitamin D" 
ORDER BY Nutr_Val DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on your tables?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, the only index is NDB_No in the table food_des

Comment: You really should index `nut_data`: I suggest at very least a simple index over `(NDB_No)`, although an optimal approach might involve a composite over `(NDB_No, Nutr_No)` together with an index on `nutr_def.Nutr_No`.  If you find performance is still unacceptable after that, do post your execution plan ("`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`") and we could consider adding some covering indexes.

Comment: @eggyal: Also index `nutr_def.NutrDesc`--used in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Woo! down to 0.8-1 second now! Would there be anything else I can do to speed up?

Comment: Read http://use-the-index-luke.com for a good tutorial in how to use indexes and when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE  nutr_def.NutrDesc="Vitamin D"` begs for `INDEX(NutrDesc)`.  So, assuming the optimizer starts with nutr_def, then it will need to move on to nut_data, which will need `INDEX(Nutr_No)`, then to food_des, needing `INDEX(NDB_No)`.

If the optimizer chooses to start with the ORDER BY, then `INDEX(Nutr_Val)` would be beneficial.  (Please qualify fields when using JOIN!  We can't tell which table that is in!)  So, if it starts with that table, follow the JOINs to see what indexes are needed on the other two tables.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...` if you need further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT food_des.Long_Desc, nut_data.Nutr_Val, nutr_def.Units
FROM food_des INNER JOIN nut_data
ON food_des.NDB_No=nut_data.NDB_No
INNER JOIN nutr_def
ON nut_data.Nutr_No=nutr_def.Nutr_No
WHERE nutr_def.NutrDesc="Vitamin D" 
ORDER BY Nutr_Val DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Then decide where you want to add index

Comment: I got

select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows
SIMPLE|nutr_def|ref|PRIMARY,NutrDesc|NutrDesc|62|const|2
SIMPLE|food_des|ALL|PRIMARY|NULL|NULL|NULL|7771
SIMPLE|nut_data|eq_ref|PRIMARY,NDB_No|PRIMARY|12|info.food_des.NDB_No,info.nutr_def.Nutr_No|1

Sorry it looks kinda messy

Comment: Looks like you don't yet have INDEX(NDB_No) on food_des.